# How to remove environment table in the pytest-html report

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-html

i am trying to remove environment table present in the pytest-html report ,but i am not sure how to do it?

i have attached the pytest-html report 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3Cu.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [relevant spot in the docs](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html#environment) states:

> The Environment section is provided by the pytest-metadata, plugin, and can be accessed via the `pytest_configure` hook:
>
> ```
> def pytest_configure(config):
>     config._metadata['foo'] = 'bar'
> ```

Modifying the `config._metadata` will effect the rendered "Environment" section. If you want to remove it completely, set the metadata to `None`:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata = None
```

Comment: Ya it is working fine thank you @hoefling but the only problem i have is it is also removing the title (i mean the report title)

Comment: The report title (the report name + the line "Report generated on ...") are not affected by this and will be still present.

Comment: ya its working fine thank you @hoefling , i had done some mistake